# How to get firstname and second maximum salary of the record using subqueries?

Tags: oracle10g

I'm new to oracle. I have to get `firstname` and second maximum salary of the record from the table using sub-queries.
I've tried below query:

```
select max(salary) 
 from employees 
where salary > (select max(salary) 
                  from empoloyees);
```

this query used to get second max salary from the table. Now I have to get `firstname` of the second salary record.

```
firstname   salary
-------------------
mani         45666 
vijay        50000 
sanjay       65000
```

Comment: What does the table look like? Can you post the schema?

Comment: Also, shouldn't that be `salary < (select max(salary) from employees)` (less than rather than greater than)?

Comment: The table like  the 1st col.name is-- firstname    and 2nd col.name is-- salary....The datas are   1st row-- mani   45666   and 2nd row vijay   50000   and 3rd row is sanjay   65000

Comment: sorry...less than...try it.... give the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstname, salary FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC)
    WHERE rownum = 2;
```

The inner `SELECT` sorts the table by `salary`, in order from greatest to least (hence `DESC`).

The outer `SELECT` takes the two fields you want from row 2 (which holds the second highest `salary`) of the sorted table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dense_rank for this.

```
select  firstname, salary
  from (select /*+ first_rows(2) */ firstname, salary, 
               dense_rank() Over (order by salary desc) r
          from employees)
 where r = 2;
```

the first_rows hint is there as to help it use an index (index on (salary) or (salary, firstname).
This may return > 1 row if 2 people happen to share the same salary (you can add `and rownum = 1` to pick just one at random).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE SAL >=(SELECT MAX (SAL) FROM EMP WHERE SAL < (SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM EMP WHERE SAL <(SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM EMP))) AND ROWNUM < 4 ORDER BY SAL
```